# Opening a new window on a different storyboard

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, storyboard, selector

I am developing an OS X app with storyboards. I get the Preview.storyboard with an Entry Point on an anonymous window with a custom ViewController. In the AppDelegate class, I get the following function.

```
func newPreviewWindow(sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard.init(name: "Preview", bundle: nil)
    let initialController = storyboard.instantiateInitialController()
    initialController!.showWindow(nil)
    initialController!.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
}
```

When running the code, the window shows, but I get the following exception:

```
2016-08-11 10:27:12.434 MyApp[1090:290439] -[NSWindowController makeKeyAndOrderFront:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000008c350
2016-08-11 10:27:12.434 MyApp[1090:290439] -[NSWindowController makeKeyAndOrderFront:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000008c350
2016-08-11 10:27:12.440 MyApp[1090:290439] (
    0   CoreFoundation             0x00007fff926284f2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib            0x00007fff97c0ef7e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation             0x00007fff926921ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation             0x00007fff92598571 ___forwarding___ + 1009
    4   CoreFoundation             0x00007fff925980f8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   MyApp                      0x0000000100005617 
...
```

Based on the exception message and search on Google and StackOverflow, I tried sending a Selector to the `makeKeyAndOrderFront` function this way :

```
func newPreviewWindow(sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard.init(name: "Preview", bundle: nil)
    let initialController = storyboard.instantiateInitialController()
    let selector = #selector(AppDelegate.newPreviewWindow(_:))
    initialController!.showWindow(nil)
    initialController!.makeKeyAndOrderFront(selector) // [A]
}
```

But then I get the following compile error on line [A]: `Cannot call value of non-function type '((AnyObject?) -> Void)!'`

How is the proper way to open the new window or to pass the Selector?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initialController!.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)` is causing a problem because `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` is not an `NSWindowController` method - it belongs to `NSWindow` (hence the *unrecognized selector* error). Cast your initial controller to your `NSWindowController` subclass, then bring the window to the front via the controller's `window` property:

```
var windowController: NSWindowController!

@IBAction func showOtherWindow(sender: AnyObject) {
    windowController = storyboard.instantiateInitialController() as! NSWindowController
    windowController.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems to fix both the exception and compilation error. Unfortunately, the window is not showing at all (strange how it was appearing when the exception was thrown on `initialController!.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)`). I do both the `windowController.showWindow(nil)` and `windowController.window!.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)` and nothing happens. Would you happen to have an idea why?

Comment: In the code you've posted ``initialController`` is a local variable. Like any other local variable, as soon as the function that created it exits, it's lost (along with the window). In other words, the window **does** appear but only until the function executes; this happens so quickly that it looks nothing happens. In your crashing code, the crash probably has the effect of pausing or freezing the function's execution. As a result the function never returns, and the window controller stays around to keep the window on screen. The solution is to assign the controller to a property.

Comment: Oh I see! It works perfectly now and I've grasped two important concepts I did not understood yet because of my java background! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You should really use `showWindow()` rather than `makeKeyAndOrderFront()`. The former does the latter, when it's appropriate, and doesn't require you to access the window to do it.